# How to loading two parts of the same file to two different matrixes? (matlab)

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I've one file (file.csv) filled with integers in the following format:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100
2,5,1,3,4,6,7,8,10,200
```

I know that using this code:

```
load('FILE.csv')
x = FILE
```

`x` will be a `NxM` matrix,where..

- `N` is the number of rows in the text file (in the example above: `N=2`)
- `M` is the number of numbers (divided by comma) in each row (in the example above: `M=10`)

My goal is something similar.

I want to get **two** matrices:

The **First** matrix (y): This is the same matrix as "x" but **without** the last column
(In the example above this is the same of loading in the matrix the following file:

```
   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
   2,5,1,3,4,6,7,8,10
```

so the result matrix is a `N*(M-1)` matrix (`N=2` , `M=10`) ==> 2 rows , 9 columns

```
   |1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 |
   |2 5 1 3 4 6 7 8 10|
```

The **Second** matrix: This is the remaining column (or more simply: a N*1 matrix and we have **a row for each element of last column**)

In the example above the matrix would be:

```
|100|
|200|
```

What is the easiest way to do this? (I'm a MATLAB beginner).

Thank you in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to manually split the variable `FILE` after loading

```
y=FILE(:,1:end-1);
x=FILE(:,end);
```

If your data file is large and you are worried about running out of memory then you can import the file using `csvread`

```
 y=csvread('file.csv',0,0,[0 0 n-1 m-2] # reads the first m-1 columns and n rows
 x=csvread('file.csv',0,m-1) %# reads the mth column
```

but you would need to know the number of rows and columns before first.

Comment: thank you for the answer. it works but there is a problem: in x is loaded just the column m (as expected) but in y is loaded just column m-1 (and I want to load ALL the columns from 1 to m-1). i tried with both methods

Comment: @dragonmnl: I had a typing error in the first solution. the line `y=...` should read `y=FILE(:,1:end-1)`.